# Gerund phrase – gerundiale Phrase?

Tags: terminology

Ich suche nach einer deutschen Entsprechung für *gerund phrase*. In der Ausgangssprache steht die zu untersuchende Phrase im Gerundium, deshalb muss ich es auch so angeben … Eine Idee?

Comment: Findet englische Sprachwissenschaft überhaupt noch auf deutsch statt? Wenn nicht, kann es sein, daß es keinen etablierten deutschen Ausdruck dafür gibt (Domänenverlust). Es gibt ein paar ganz wenige Google-Treffer für _Gerundialphrase_.

Comment: ... naa, es ist für eine kontrastive Analyse und die Erläuterungen müssen auf Deutsch gemacht werden, drum bin ich auf der Suche nach einem passenden Wort... Danke schön!!! : )

Comment: Auch wenn's wahrscheinlich nicht der richtige Begriff ist, käme ich spontan auf "Gerundialphrase", äquivalent zu Pronominalphrase, Verbalphrase, oder Nominalphrase.

Comment: Ich wollte erst *Gerundiumsphrase* vorschlagen, aber *Gerundialphrase* klingt doch deutlich besser.

Comment: Nicht für alle grammatischen Fachbegriffe gibt es auch deutsche Wörter. Insbesondere dann, wenn es die damit bezeichnete Konstruktion im Deutschen gar nicht gibt (was hier ja der Fall ist). Begriffe wie *Gerundiumsphrase* oder *Gerundialphrase* treffen vermutlich zwar recht gut, was mit *gerund phrase* gemeint sein könnte, diese Begriffe sind aber nicht etabliert. Will man sie dennoch verwenden, sollte man sie daher am Beginn eines Textes ausdrücklich definieren, damit später klar ist, was damit gemeint ist.

Comment: Vielen Dank Euch allen!!! Nehme jede Antwort gerne an! Die Idee mit der Definition am Anfang des Textes ist auch sehr gut!!! Danke schön!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die beste Möglichkeit scheint mir, eine solche Phrase als **Gerundialphrase** zu bezeichnen, in Anlehnung an ähnliche Begriffe wie *Nominalphrase* oder *Partizipialphrase*. Diese Bezeichnung wurde einige Dutzend Male in der Literatur verwendet, wie [eine Suche auf Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22gerundialphrase%22) zeigt. Die Belege sind überwiegend älter, mutmaßlich weil heute kaum noch in deutscher Sprache über die Grammatik der Sprachen publiziert wird, die über so etwas verfügen. – Vereinzelt wurde auch von [Gerundialgruppe](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22gerundialgruppe%22) gesprochen.